# selected doesn't work in reactive forms Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have a dropdown menu with a couple of options and I want the first one to be selected by default, but it doesn't work. I suspect this is because in the .ts file I initialize the control with the undifined value by default, but even if I try to pass a value inside it still nothing happens, how can I fix that?

HTML

```
<select  formControlName = "unit_measurement"  name="unit_measurment" id="unit_measurment">
            <option  selected disabled value="">Выберите ед. измерения</option>
            <option *ngFor="let um of unitMeasurements" [ngValue] = "um" value="">{{ um.value }}</option>
        </select>
```

TS

```
addForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(undefined,[
      Validators.required
    ]),
    quantity: new FormControl(undefined,[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(0)
    ]),
    unit_cost: new FormControl(undefined,[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(0)
    ]),
    unit_measurement: new FormControl(undefined,[
      Validators.required
    ])
  })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFA7R.png)

I expect the first option tag to get selected by default

Answer (score 0):

1. update the Angular form like this

Create unit_measurements enum and add the value into the form controller

example for enum

```
export enum unitMeasurement{
     //  unit measurements...
};
```

you have to remove by default and add the default value you want

```
addForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(undefined,[
          Validators.required
        ]),
        quantity: new FormControl(undefined,[
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(0)
        ]),
        unit_cost: new FormControl(undefined,[
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(0)
        ]),
        unit_measurement: new FormControl(undefined,[
          Validators.required
        ])
      })
```

2. other one you can setValue for fromController in ngOnInit() example

   `this.workOrderForm.get('unit_measurement').setValue('Выберите ед. измерения');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
ngOnInit() {
    // get the unit measurements (i guess they come from a service?)
    SOME_SERVICE.subscribe({
        next: (unitMeasurements) => {

            if (unitMEasurements.length > 0) {
                // Update the form values all at once (just unit_measurement in this case)
                this.addForm.patchValue({
                    // just selecting the first in array
                    unit_measurement: unitMeasurements[0]
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```